# Android compass correction on different devices

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I have got a small application that uses compass readings on my device (Xperia Neo V). When testing it, I got very satisfying results while pointing the desired direction. But I tested it on a Samsung Galaxy S3, and I run the same application on my neo V at the same time, the two devices did not show exactly the same direction. There was a drift about 10 degrees.

So, as an electronical engineer I know that different digital compass sensors may give different values due to design, but I coulnd't find an efficient solution to that yet. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would try some experiments using rotations in different direction on both devices in the same environment to find any correlation on the results. Possibly there's an offset that should be removed. A real pure compass device could help to estimate the noise level.